# web site not rendered properly in IE 9 and below (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-9, format

Im having an issue getting my site to work properly in IE9 and earleir (it works fine in IE10 as well as FireFox). The issue is that upon visiting the home page (or any of the pages that the navigation bar links to), each navigation bar link is listed on top of the other instead of side by side. The odd part is that once a search button is clicked on the home page, everything starts to work fine.

I've searched the site and tried recommended suggestions, like changing the contents of the meta tag in the files, to no avail.

Edit: Someone suggested I include a screenshot, but I am unable to do so as I do not have enough reputation points yet.

HTML file to include for navigation bar:

```
//<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE10'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='jsddm.css'>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

  $("ul.jsddm li").hover(function(){
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

     }, function(){
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

     });

   });
</script>



<ul class="jsddm">
<li><a href="home"><img src="./styles/icons/sitelogolowres.png"> APPraisal</a>
<li><a href="#">OS</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Rating</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<br/><br/>
```

CSS file:

```
ul.jsddm
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 2.0em;

}

ul.jsddm a
    {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

ul.jsddm a:hover
{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

ul.jsddm > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20%;
}

ul.jsddm li ul li
{
    list-style:none;
}

ul.jsddm ul
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 33px;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    ul.jsddm, ul.flyout
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 2.0em;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    ul.jsddm li
    {
        float: left;
        width: 19%;
        position:relative;
    }
    ul.jsddm a
    {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #333;
        border: 1px solid #444;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: auto;
    }
    ul.flyout li
    {
        width: 100%;
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
    ul.jsddm a:hover
    {
        color: #000;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    ul.flyout
    {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:34px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
    }
    ul.jsddm li:hover ul.flyout
    {
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <ul class="jsddm">
        <li><a href="home">APPraisal</a>
        <li><a href="#">OS</a>
            <ul class="flyout">
                <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Rating</a>
            <ul class="flyout">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the drop down to CSS. The main issue was ul.jsddm > li, it only styles the first li and has ie issues without a default li style

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That resolved the issue with the stacking of the links. For some reason though, the drop down options are not working anymore (i.e. Andorid, iOS, etc). Do I have to include anything else to make the flyout option work?

Comment: Did the drop downs work before on andriod and ios? that would surprise me as I didnt think hover worked on mobile devices. Do the drop downs work ok on web browsers?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the drop down is not working in IE. I just typed Android and iOS to clarify what drop down mean. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: what version of IE are you using? It seems to work ok on mine in 7 and 8

Comment: Im using IE10. To make sure that the code is compatible with older versions im using an IE emulator (http://cloudinternetexplorer.com/). The emulator seemed accurate but if the code is not working for you it might not be as accurate as I thought.